# Wrapping Current Category Text with Span in Wordpress 2.8.6

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm showing categories with this codes. Normally there is no problem.

```
<?php
$categories = wp_list_categories('current_category=1&hide_empty=0&title_li=&echo=0&link_before=<span>&link_after=</span>');
$categories = preg_replace('/title=\"(.*?)\"/','',$categories);
echo $categories;
?>
```

But i want to wrap current category's text into `<span>` tag for showing current category image.

In short:
`<a href="#">Home</a>` to `<a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>`.

How i can do it with PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of wordpress are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your second line of code with this:

```
$categories = preg_replace(
    array('/title=\"(.*?)\"/','/(<a.*?>)(.*?)(<\/a>)/'),
    array('','$1<span>$2</span>$3'),
    $categories);
```

And it will continue to remove the `title` tags as well as add the `<span></span>` inside each of the `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); foreach ($categories as $cat) {echo '<a href="'.get_option('home').'/'.get_option('category_base').'/'.$cat->category_nicename.'/"><span>'.$cat->cat_name.'</span></a>'; } ?>
```

Comment: It's working and wrapping `<a>`'s into `<span>`. But i can't use `current_category=1` argument. So it can't add `.current-cat` class to `<li>`s.